# Why does my function return a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, splice

I have some code which is meant to do the following:

> Given two arrays of strings `a1` and `a2` return a sorted array `r` in
>   lexicographical order of the strings of `a1` which are substrings of
>   strings of `a2`.
>  Arrays are written in "general" notation.

Now I'm doing a test where `array1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"]` and `array2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]`.
I think I've got it, but I don't understand why the function only returns the array `["arp", "strong"]` when in the last for loop I replace `newArray.splice(l, l+1)` with `newArray.splice(k, k+1)`.
Could anyone tell me why that is?

```js
function inArray(array1, array2) {
    var newArray = [];
    var sortedArray = [];
    for (var i in array2) {
        for (var j in array1) {
            if (array2[i].includes(array1[j])) {
                newArray.push(array1[j]);
            };
        };
    };
    sortedArray = newArray.sort();
    for (var k = 0; k < newArray.length; k++) {
        for (var l = 0; l < newArray.length; l++) {
            if (newArray[k] === newArray[l] && k != l) {
                newArray.splice(l, l + 1)
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedArray;
};

console.log(inArray(["arp", "live", "strong"], ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]));
```

Comment: Can you use ES6? If so, Sets can help a lot with the duplication thing.

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: Don't use `splice`. It's confusing and bug-prone.

Comment: Should you be returning ```newArray``` instead of ```sortedArray```? Or using ```sortedArray``` in the last for loop?

Comment: Because when `k=0` and `l > 0`, it removes `0+1` element at `0` index. So it will remove `arp`.

Comment: @Deep His question isn't about the code in the snippet, it's about what happens if he changes the `splice()` line.

Comment: @CUGreen `newArray` and `sortedArray` are the same array, because `sort()` modifies the array in place.

Comment: The second loop is just removing duplicates, right? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're overcomplicating it a bit ;)

```js
a1 = ["arp", "live", "strong", "bazooka"]
a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]


result = a1
    .filter(x => a2.some(y => y.includes(x)))
    .sort();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the second argument to `splice()` isn't the end position of the splice, but the count of elements that should be removed. So when `k = 1`, you removed 2 elements, not just the element at index `1`.

Both `newArray.splice(l, 1)` and `newArray.splice(k, 1)` work correctly.

```js
function inArray(array1,array2){
 var newArray = [];
 var sortedArray = [];
  for (var i in array2) {
   for (var j in array1) {
    if (array2[i].includes(array1[j])) {
     newArray.push(array1[j]);
    };
   };
  };
  sortedArray = newArray.sort();

  for (var k = 0; k < newArray.length; k++) {
   for (var l = 0; l < newArray.length; l++) {
    if (newArray[k] === newArray[l] && k != l) {
     newArray.splice(k, 1);

    }
   }
  }
  return sortedArray;
};

console.log(inArray(["arp", "live", "strong"], ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments already you get the answer. Use ES2015/ES6 always you can, benefit of it's adventages.

```js
const words1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"];
const words2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"];
const final = [];

words1.forEach(v => {
  words2.forEach(v2 => {
    if (v2.includes(v)) {
      final.push(v);
    }
  });
});

const finalSorted = [...new Set(final.sort())];

// just to add html
const pre = document.getElementById('result');

finalSorted.forEach(v => {
  let content = pre.textContent;
  content += `\n- ${v}`;
  pre.textContent = content;
});
```

```html
<label>Result:</label>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```